# Import from excel to datatable skipping last column values

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, excel, import, datatable

I am trying to import data from excel file to datatable. But problem is that last column values are skipped. Values of rest of columns are perfect. My excel file contains this:

[image]

And after import data in datatable is as below :

[image]

My code is as :

```
  Dim connExcel As New OleDbConnection(constr)
    Dim cmdExcel As New OleDbCommand()
    Dim oda As New OleDbDataAdapter()
    Dim dt As New DataTable()
    cmdExcel.Connection = connExcel

    'Read Data from First Sheet
    connExcel.Open()
    cmdExcel.CommandText = "SELECT * From [Sheet1$]"
    oda.SelectCommand = cmdExcel
    oda.Fill(dt)
    connExcel.Close()
```

Connections Strings are as :

```
<add name="ExcelCon12" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=Excel 8.0" />
<add name="ExcelCon4" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=Excel 8.0"/>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is there any chance you have an off-by-one error in displaying the datatable?

Comment: No, what surprise me is that if i added on more column after this, values of that are populated without any problem. But if I copy paste this column in excel file to any other column, problem for this column remain still. Then , I created another column, inserted same values in that and deleted this column, after that , renamed new column as Credit. And it solved unexpectedly. Seems problem was intrinsically in column somehow!!

Comment: @ubaidashrafmasoody I mention it probably lay's within the column itself in my answer, but it could be something else that I have mentioned as well...

Answer (score 1):

I would endorse the idea that this is indeed a bug in Excel / OleDb. @ubaidashrafmasoody is correct, and I've reproduced the same behavior today. The other offered answer, that it can be fixed by setting

`Extended Properties="Excel 8.0;IMEX=1"`

does not seem correct, because I encountered this behavior with this already set in my connection string.

The particulars of the buggy behavior is this (though it is possible that editing: If the very LAST column has (majority) empty cells in the first few (presumably 8) rows, then the column doesn't appear in scope to any SQL statement. (This arbitrarily fixes itself after certain edits, exactly as @ubaidashrafmasoody described.) For instance, if I had five columns, Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4, and Column5, with the values (other than Column5 in the header row) blank, then:

`SELECT * From [Sheet1$]`

would only return 4 columns.

If I were to name only four of the columns, e.g.:

`SELECT [Column1], [Column2], [Column3], [Column4] From [Sheet1$]`

then it would return correctly. But if I named the fifth column:

`SELECT [Column1], [Column2], [Column3], [Column4], [Column5] From [Sheet1$]`

then it errors out with a message that the value of the parameter for [Column5] is not specified. Or, without the brackets, that there is no such field.

Even explicitly specifying the range in the SQL statement:

`SELECT [Column1], [Column2], [Column3], [Column4], [Column5] From [Sheet1$A1:E55]`

or

`SELECT * From [Sheet1$A1:E55]`

does not work to retrieve that fifth column.

However, an easy 'fix' is to add a new blank column named e.g. Column6 after this . Suddenly, Column5 becomes visible, in spite of its NULLs.

Answer (score 0):

From the look's of the code you have provided I'm not seeing an issue. I believe the issue lay's within the column itself; for example: mixed values (bg123 | 1234). Can this column be mixed; integers, strings etc? ADO.Net chooses the DataType based on the column particularly from the majority of the values. Each cell is then cast to that type that ADO.Net choose's it to be. If you have more integer's than it would be cast as numeric on the other hand if not it will be cast as string...

One solution is to use `ExtendedProperties` within your connection string; indicate's your importing the data.

Try the approach below...

```
 Extended Properties=""Excel8.0;IMEX=1""" 'This is to tell it to not care about the types...(mixed); be sure to include the `"` around the `ExtendedProperties` as well.
```

Your connection string now...

```
 "Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;IMEX=1"""
```

Comment: What surprised me is that if i added on more columns after this, values of that are populated without any problem. But if I copy paste this column in excel file to any other column, problem for this column remains still. Then , I created another column, inserted same values in that and deleted this column, after that , renamed new column as Credit. And it solved unexpectedly. Seems problem was intrinsically in column somehow!! But what exactly was the problem?

Comment: @ubaidashrafmasoody please read my answer as it explains this. It's probably confused on what type to cast them to... If there's more 'null' or empty values than integers (numeric) it will cast these cells to strings, but if your type is numeric it fails for every cell in that column.

Comment: @ubaidashrafmasoody in the screenshot you provided it show's exactly that; most of your columns values in debit are integers it will cast that columns datatype to an integer. On the other hand your last column has more empty values which will cast those as strings, but your data consist of integers but will fail as it doesn't know how to handle them.

Comment: I copied cell contents, exactly, number of empty cells or non empty cells remained same.