# While binding a retrieved excel columns in DataSet all columns are retrieved bind except the last column

Tags: c#

I have a requirement to import the excel file in ASP.NET MVC. The importing is working as needed, there are 78 columns in the excel file.  all the columns are imported except the last column.

How could I retrive last column from the excel file?

```
string conString = string.Empty;
                        if (getFileExtension.ToLower() == ".xls")
                        {
                            conString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + getFileName + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\""; ;
                        }
                        else if (getFileExtension.ToLower() == ".xlsx")
                        {
                            conString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + getFileName + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
                        }
                        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(conString);
                        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed) con.Open();
                        DataTable ExcelSheets = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, new object[] { null, null, null, "TABLE" });
                        string SpreadSheetName = ExcelSheets.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
                        string query = "SELECT * FROM [" + SpreadSheetName + "]";
                        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, con);
                        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
                        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                        da.Fill(ds);
                        da.Dispose();
                        con.Close();
                        con.Dispose();
```

Comment: What exactly is in the last column? Is it a specific type of information different from the rest? Do your columns have headers?

Comment: in a excel column "BZ"  header name is "CustomerID" and value is 1

Answer (score 1):

According to [Import from excel to datatable skipping last column values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27957139/import-from-excel-to-datatable-skipping-last-column-values), this may be an Excel or OleDb bug.

As a workaround, you might consider modifying the Excel sheet so as to add an additional column header at the end, with no data in the column. Then, the column that is skipped during import will be the one you don't need.